# Trying to display images (images url saved in mysql and images are stored in a folder) in jsp but it is not working

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am able to store product image in a folder and its "URL" in database but when I tried to display image is it not showing. When I saw the page source in a browser it shows correct URL but no image is shown.
Even path stores in a database is also correctly stored.

prodimages.jsp

```
  <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label>Select Product</label> 
    <c:forEach var="product" items="${listProduct}">
        <select name="prodID" class="form-control">  
         <option value="<c:out value="${product.getId()}" />">
            <c:out value="${product.getProductName()}" /></option>  
        </select>  
   </c:forEach>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Select file:</label>
       <input type="file" class="form-control"  id="file" placeholder="insert image" name="file" value="Upload">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group"></div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Button</button>
 </form>
```

Here is my uploadservlet.java

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public UploadServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
private static final String SAVE_DIR = "images";
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
    {
     try {
            String savePath = "C:\\WORKSPACE-ECLIPSE\\EStore\\productImg" + File.separator + SAVE_DIR;
        File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);
            if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) 
            {
                fileSaveDir.mkdir();
             }
            String prodID = request.getParameter("prodID");
            Part part = request.getPart("file");
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            out.println(fileName);
            out.println("\n" + prodID);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
            for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
            String fileName = extractFileName(part);
            part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
        
            }
                    String query = "INSERT INTO image_link (name, photourl) values (?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement pst;
            pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pst.setString(1, prodID);
            String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
            pst.setString(2, filePath);
            pst.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception ex) 
      {
        out.println("error" + ex);
      }
 }
  }
  private String extractFileName(Part part) 
  {
  String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");
  String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");
  for (String s : items) {
        if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) 
        {
            return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);
       }
    }
        return "";
   }
```

Here is my photoretrieval.jsp

```
    String image = null;
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String iurl1=null;
    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopperdb","root","manager");
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from image_link where name = 1");%>
            <table border="2">
            <tr><th>DISPLAYING IMAGE</th></tr>
            <tr><td>Image 2</td></tr>
            <tr><td>
            <%while(rs.next()){%>
             <img src="<%=rs.getString("photourl") %>" width="500" height="500"/>
             <%}%>
            </td></tr>
            </table>
            <%}
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        out.println("DB problem"); 
        return;
    }
    finally 
    {
    try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) 
    {  e.printStackTrace(); }
  }
```

Comment: Hi copy that url and paste in your browser url and see if that image show up

Comment: Yes Swati, when I paste URL in browser image is showing. Even when I saw page source (ctrl+U) the URL is same in <img src> but still image is not shown

Comment: Not sure then where problem might be .. as you say that url show image in browser as well .Lastly , can you change your `src` like this - > `src="<%=rs.getString('photourl') %>"` ?

Comment: I am still facing this problem. But when  I run this into eclipse's internal browser it is working fine. So can anyone explain this or solve my problem